App Runner Django Deployment Error Python Version3.11
I'm trying to deploy my Django backend to AppRunner.
My apprunner.yml is this;
version: 1.0
runtime: python311
build:
  commands:
    build:        
      - pip3 install pipenv
      - pipenv install
    post-build:
      - python3 manage.py test
  env:
    - name: DEBUG
      value: "on"
    - name: SECRET_KEY
      value: "django-insecure-a=0f%a$+p$cyb)xobnaa42@gypz3q&f-!n&03&_t$t#_bn2+h4"
    - name: ALLOWED_HOSTS
      value: "*"
run:
  runtime-version: 3.11
  pre-run:  
    - pip3 install pipenv
    - pipenv install
  command: pipenv run gunicorn django_apprunner.wsgi --log-file -
  network: 
    port: 8000
    env: 8000  
  env:
    - name: DEBUG
      value: "on"
    - name: SECRET_KEY
      value: "django-insecure-a=0f%a$+p$cyb)xobnaa42@gypz3q&f-!n&03&_t$t#_bn2+h4"
    - name: ALLOWED_HOSTS
      value: "*"

In the Application Log File this error comes;
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
I tried to deploy my Django Backend via AppRunner but I got this error.

hello! were you able to solve your problem? I am going through the same error
